# Cannot do Inner join in CDbCriteria

Tags: join, yii

This is mysqli query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.company_id,t.image,t.text,t.date, t.title AS c_title
FROM news t
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.company_id=t.company_id ORDER BY t.date DESC
LIMIT 20" or die ("ERROR ". mysqli_error($link));
```

I want to write in CDbCriteria

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN companies c ON t.company_id=c.company_id';
if ($place>0){
    $Criteria->condition = "t.company_id = :place";
    $Criteria->params = array(':place'=>$place);
}
$Criteria->order = "t.date DESC";
$Criteria->limit = 20;
$Criteria->select='t.company_id,t.image,t.text,t.date,c.title AS c_title';
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('News',
    array(
        'criteria'=>$Criteria,
        'pagination'=>false
    )
);
```

Error Property "News.c_title" is not defined

Comment: Are you using this in a grid/list view? If so please add it.

Comment: No, the problem is that I can not take c.title from Companies,it looks for it in news table

Answer (score 1):

The property `c_title` is not defined in your News model (fields from your news table will be available as properties automatically, but c_title is an alias of title and not a field of of your table).

Put this in your News model:

`public $c_title;`

Comment: yes c_title is not a field of table News, it is in table companies. Normally in mysqli query i wrote select c.title AS c_title, but here it looks for it in news table, not in companies